# Replacing an \u with \\u in a string using java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace an \u in a url.

C:\testing\bing\utest\university.txt

when i use `url=url.replaceAll("\\u", "\\\\u");` I am getting the below error May i know how to replace the \u with \u or escaping the \u

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal Unicode escape sequence near index 2
\u
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
url.replaceAll("\\\\u", "\\\\\\\\u")
```

Will produce:

```
C:\testing\bing\\utest\\university.txt
```

Comment: There is no need to use regex to avoid crazy escaping actually.

Comment: anubhava is right, if you really insist on using regex, at least you should use quoteReplacement :

url.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\u"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\u"))

Answer (score 5):

You can actually ditch the regex and use non-regex method `String#replace` for this:

```
String repl = "C:\\testing\\bing\\utest\\university.txt".replace("\\u", "\\\\u");
//=> C:\testing\bing\\utest\\university.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use it like this : `url=url.replaceAll("\\\\u", "\\\\\\\\u");` . The first argument to `replaceAll()` is a `regex` and the second argument is a `string`.

Why? :

If you look at the code of `matcher.appendReplacement()` which is called from `replaceAll()`, you have :

```
 while (cursor < replacement.length()) {
            char nextChar = replacement.charAt(cursor);
            if (nextChar == '\\') {
```

So, each `\` will have to be considered which leads to 4 *2 =8 `\`s in the code

Comment: I tried this way `url=url.replaceAll("\\\\u", "\\\\u"); `which result in `C:\testing\bing\utest\university.txtt` but it should be `C:\testing\bing\\utest\\university.txt`

Comment: @Ramesh - Please update your question with the code you tried

Comment: Your second argument is wrong for two reasons: 1) "\\u" doesn't produce `\\u` literal but `\u` literal 2) both arguments in `replaceAll` are not simple literals, first is regex, second (replacement) is special in a way that it can access content matched by regex via `$x` where `x` is name of group. This means that we need some way to create `$` literal which is done by same syntax as in regex: `\$` but this also mean that ``\`` will be special character there, which means that to create such literal in replacement we need to escape it twice: in Java String and in replacement pattern.

Comment: @Pshemo - Yes. You are right.. My bad.. Corrected the answer.. Thank you :)